# How did Princess Leia remember her mother?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In the last scene of *Return of the Jedi*, Princess Leia tells Luke that she remembers their mother, and she says, "She was so beautiful and kind but always sad". This statement looks like she have spent good enough time to observe her behaviour.

But in *Revenge of the Sith*, we see that their mother dies while giving birth to both of them.

So how did Princess Leia remembered anything about her mother?

Comment: A complete guess would be archive footage of her that Leia might have had access to. Or some sort of force vision. Like I say, complete guess.

Comment: She may have had Force memories or visions of her mother when she was younger and probably thinks they were real.

Comment: I think Mooz has it right, The Force... remember what Yoda said: Through the Force, things you will see. Other places. The future…the past.

Comment: @Mooz  Then the same should have happened with Luke too, as Force flow good in Entire family. How came he end up asking Leia about that?

Comment: @rptwsthi: I am not sure how canon this is any longer but I believe it had been established that some Force users are more adept at taping into certain aspects of Force.  I seem to recall a character in Jedi Academy that could absorb, or perhaps, redirect energy (somewhat like the Emperor in Return of the Jedi).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the original novelization, Padmé [**doesn't die in childbirth**](http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarsglossaryandfaq/a/SWAR_leia-remembers-mother.htm):

> In the novelization of Return of the Jedi, written by James Kahn, Obi-Wan Kenobi tells Luke that Anakin didn't know his lover was pregnant when he became Darth Vader, and Obi-Wan hid her away to protect her. **After she gave birth, Obi-Wan took Luke to Tatooine and she took Leia to Alderaan**.

These events are completely retconed / contradicted in Revenge of the Sith.

> In Children of the Jedi by Barbara Hambly, Leia mentions being raised by her aunts, suggesting that her adoptive mother died when she was young. However, Star Wars: The Annotated Screenplays states that George Lucas intended for Leia to remember her real mother, **and Leia's Star Wars Databank entry states that her memories are of Padmé**.

But as Mooz pointed out above, like her brother, she is force-sensitive even if she's never understood or trained her abilities.

This opens the door to all sorts of force-enabled flashbacks / images.